# What does active fragment has cleared index: -1 mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got an Activity with a custom sliding menu for a tab-like interface.  For some reason, one (and only one) of my fragments has this error and I can't seem to find what it's doing.

Here is the stack trace.

```
E/FragmentManager(13024): Failure saving state: active SettingsFragment{427b2918} has cleared index: -1
E/FragmentManager(13024): Activity state:
E/AndroidRuntime(13024): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(13024): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: active SettingsFragment{427b2918} has cleared index: -1
E/AndroidRuntime(13024):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1700)
E/AndroidRuntime(13024):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:527)
E/AndroidRuntime(13024):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime(13024):    at com.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(SlidingFragmentActivity.java:50)
E/AndroidRuntime(13024):    at com.client.activities.BaseMenuActivity.onSaveInstanceState(BaseMenuActivity.java:139)
```

The fragment is super simple.  All it does is subclass SherlockFragment and override onCreateView and onActivityCreated to setup the view.  It's got some buttons that navigate to other fragments.

I can't even reliably reproduce this error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

in this case i Guess when you want to attach you're fragment , it seen like my code

```
       case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, **xxxx**, "2");
            ft.detach(**yyyyyyy**);
            ft.attach(**yyyyyyy**);
```

code below is wrong and correct code is

```
         case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, **xxxx**, "2");
            ft.detach(**xxxx**);
            ft.attach(**xxxx**);
```

maybe you have error like this and i hope it be helpful for you